# Hibernate make same aliases for different joins

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose, we have 3 entity

```xml
<class name="AEntity" table="A" abstract="true">
    <id name="id">
        <column name="ID"/>
    </id>

    <joined-subclass table="Aa" name="AaEntity">
        <key column="key"/>
        <many-to-one name="b" class="BEntity">
            <column name="B_ID"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </joined-subclass>

    <joined-subclass table="Ab" name="AbEntity">
        <key column="key"/>
        <many-to-one name="b" class="BEntity">
            <column name="B_ID"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </joined-subclass>
</class>
```

---

```xml
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Parent" table="parent">
        <id name="id">
            <column name="ID"/>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="a" class="AEntity">
            <column name="a_ID" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

```xml
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="BEntity" table="B">
        <id name="id">
            <column name="ID"/>
        </id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Then, we make criteria request

```java
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Parent.class);
criteria.createAlias("a","a");
criteria.createAlias("a.b","b");
criteria.list();
```

And get next sql

```sql
select this_.ID as ID1_5_3_,
       this_.a_ID as a2_5_3_,
       a1_.ID as ID1_2_0_,
       a1_.B_ID as B2_2_0_,
       a1_1_.B_ID as B2_0_0_,
       a1_2_.B_ID as B2_1_0_,
       case when a1_1_.key is not null then 1 when a1_2_.key is not null then 2 when a1_.ID is not null then 0 end as clazz_0_,
       b2_.ID as ID1_3_1_,
       b2_.C_ID as C2_3_1_,
       b2_.ID as ID1_3_2_,
       b2_.C_ID as C2_3_2_
from parent this_
inner join A a1_ on this_.a_ID=a1_.ID
left outer join Aa a1_1_ on a1_.ID=a1_1_.key
left outer join Ab a1_2_ on a1_.ID=a1_2_.key
inner join B b2_ on a1_1_.B_ID=b2_.ID
inner join B b2_ on a1_2_.B_ID=b2_.ID
```

We can see that B table joins two times and have same name b2_. Is it bug? And how make two joins but with different name of B table.
Okay?

Answer (score 0):

Try aliases like

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Parent.class, "parent");
criteria.createAlias("parent.a","a");
criteria.createAlias("parent.a.AaEntity.b","aab");
criteria.createAlias("parent.a.AbEntity.b","abb");
criteria.list();
```

PS: I have not tested this and it may not work as it is, but this will give you an idea on how to force the alias names.

Comment: I got it, but "could not resolve property: AaEntity of: ru.todo100.hibernate.AEntity"

Comment: I see that both are `joined-subclass`es and both of them referring to same `many-to-one` entity. Can you comment out `criteria.createAlias("a.b","b");` and try? I hope you may need to follow a different strategy (table-per-class with discriminator column)

Comment: If i comment this line, then there are not joins. This strategy exists because may be third subclass without "b" field, but first and second with. Every class AaEntity and BbEntity has own BEntity. I googled every day and nothing answers on this topic... Many people asked and silence. I find solution because architecture of application has current structure.  I think it's hibernate bug.....

Comment: It seems to be a limitation with `Criteria`. Simplest thing you can do is, write your own HQL instead of using criteria.